# Does an associative array represent a mapping?

Tags: terminology, data-structures, hash-tables

An associative array is a set of pairs (key, value).

Does it represent a mapping, or a relation (i.e. does it allow the same key to be associated to different values)?

Does it represent an injective mapping only, or does it allow different keys to be associated to the same value?

Can a hash table implement any associative array, or just some special types of associative array?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If the sentence you give is the whole definition, then an associative array is a relation and not necessarily injective.

A hash table can implement only mappings, but it does not require them to be injective.